# Can't find module (__init__.py is present) and I'm copying a tutorial exactly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I see other questions related to this but none of the answers apply here, from what I've seen.

I have a little nothing app that looks like:

```
.
├── ds
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── stack.py
└── tests
    └── test_stack.py
```

`test_stack.py` has an import line: `from ds.stack import Stack` and `stack.py` just creates and passes a class called `Stack`.

When in the top level dir (from which `tree` was run), I run `python3 tests/test_stack.py`, get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ds'`

I've checked this with someone in Discord already and it worked on their machine...and obviously the person who is running the tutorial.

I did, at one point, put this directory in my `PYTHONPATH` and that seemed to avoid the error but I don't want to have to do that when I'm just doing random little things like this...and according to the tutorial and the person I conferred with, I shouldn't have to.

Ideas?

Comment: It `test_stack.py` were up one level, it would work.    As it is, it won't be found.  You can do `import os, sys` / `sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/..'))`

Comment: @TimRoberts unfortunately, that's exactly how it is in the tutorial.  I've been making sure of that for about 3 hours now.

Comment: Usually you are using a test runner application (like `pytest` or `python -m unittest`) from the project root to prevent this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- add _*init*_.py files in your tests directory
- make the parent directory (of ds and tests) the current working directory and run `python -m tests.test_stack`

Now, as suggested by @Klaus D., to properly run your tests, you will need to install something like pytest and then run `pytest ./tests`